# Should we add null to the list Collection.singletonlist or just make whole list null?

Tags: java

I do have question about adding null to the list in my example I will use `Collections.singletonList(value)`

So lets say I do have somethin like this:

```
String value = null;
List<String> test = Collections.singletonList(value);
```

in this case I will get singleton list which, contains null. So we do have List object which is wrapping single null value.

So my question is about adding check on `value` variable.

```
String value = null;
List<String> test;
if(value == null){
   test = null;
}
else{
   test = Collections.singletonList(value);
}
```

is it worth to do?

Comment: A list with `null` and no list at all aren't the same thing. Perhaps what you really want is `Collections.emptyList()`.

Comment: Another use full info: The `Collections.emptyList()` is just one immutable list instance of `Collections.EMPTY_LIST`. So, it's a useful filler for null lists that does not take extra memory, no matter how many places you use in the program.

Comment: Note, that both `Collections.emptyList()` and `Collections.singletonList()` are immutable. In case you need to create mutable lists, just use `new ArrayList()` (or other type of list) and optionally put an item in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a list with a single `null` to indicate there was no value to return is very uncommon and would surprise people. The most common pattern when you want to indicate there is no result (and you are returning a collection type) is to return an empty collection. Returning null would be less common but still not entirely surprising.

Comment: I agree. Puting null value to the List is a really bad idea. If there is no values a normal solution is to return an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know if the value to be added is null or not, you could define a list of optionals like this : `List<Optional<String>> test`, add your items with `Optional.ofNullable(value)` and then only check if the value is null when reading it from the list